# Plural of "coming out?"

Tags: grammatical-number, compounds

As "coming out of the closet" has become ubiquitous in recent years, what would the plural be? Would it follow the rule of "goings-on" or be a hyphenated "coming-outs" or something else entirely?

Comment: No idiomatic answer has been established, to my knowledge.  You either wing it or tiptoe around it.

Comment: There is no 'rule of "goings-on" '. "Sending offs" (sometimes hyphenated) is more common than "sendings off" on Google, and different dictionaries differ in their recommendations. // More recent usages tend to be more tolerant of more regular patterning, eg _computer mouses_.

Comment: "All the recent comings‐out" would sound reasonable to me, unlike "coming‐outs", "outcomings" etc. But I agree with Hot Licks, there is nothing really established. If you're looking for a safe option, it's to stick to the singular ("all the recent coming out", hyphenated or not) or talk around it ("instances of coming out").

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Surely *computer mouses* is in an entirely different category, just like *car windows*. Why would the plural be anything else? But I think *sendings-off* is correct. If more people use *sending-offs* it is because a majority of people are getting it wrong. *Comings-out* is the way to go, almost certainly, in my book. Our educational system is now plagued by this idea that we must never make it too hard for children.

Comment: @WS2 Are you saying that all the Americans who have now adopted Webster's recommendations on spellings are wrong? They now outnumber UK anglophones. Language changes. Usage trumps shibboleth adherence. 'Mouses' is a novel plural for 'mouse'; this does not make it wrong. And take a look at [these Google Ngrams for cul-de-sacs and culs-de-sac](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cul-de-sacs%2Cculs-de-sac&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccul%20-%20de%20-%20sacs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cculs%20-%20de%20-%20sac%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It is entirely unhelpful to tell people who are eager to know what to do and how to do it that it doesn't really matter, because in American it can be "A", in Britain you can use "B", but in Australia it's perfectly acceptable to say "C". I think that neither American or UK anglophones are in the majority when it comes to users of English any more, so force majeur would then make it okay if English were to become dominated by Chinese or Indians who had only a very basic knowledge of the language? Bye, Shakespeare, bye Twain, bye Gettysburg Address. Me speaky English, you to?

Comment: @Joost Kiefte You misrepresent me grossly. What I'm saying is that people who adhere to traditional rules because 'that's what they were taught' are being hypocritical as the rules they were taught are almost certainly going to be different from those in existence 200 years previously (and quite possibly from those taught in rival establishments). I'm not against rules; language wouldn't work without them. I'm against pseudo-rules, especially guidelines preached as binding laws. // Pluralisation of compounds is not totally regular, even in 'Standard English'.

Comment: Closely related: [What's the plural of “picking up”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227725/whats-the-plural-of-picking-up) (which contains the associated question 'What's the plural form of "picking up"? It's a gerund. What are the pluralization rules for gerunds? And if there's a better word for it, please suggest them.')

Comment: @WS2 Do you dispute the views of the Memidex (Princeton WordNet) lexicographers:  **washing-up** (washing) /
Definition: the washing of dishes, and so on, after a meal /
Class: act noun (acts and actions) /
Plural: washing-ups / ?

Comment: Whatever you say, old potato, whatever you say.

Comment: @Joost Kiefte I'm glad that you agree that you have totally misrepresented me. Now how about a retraction?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Apologies, I admit to having picked up the wrong end of the stick re *computer mouse*. I misunderstood you to be using it as part of the compounds debate, not an issue of *mouses* versus *mice*. (How interesting though that my browser's spell-checker underlines *mouses* in red.) But no if anyone wants the plural of a modern device to be *mouses*, who am I to argue? And after all the plural of *mongoose* is *mongooses*. But in the rare event that I were to use *washing-up* as a countable noun, I fear it would have to be *washings-up*.

Comment: @Joost Kiefte I agree with Hot Licks when he says about the plural form to use here "No idiomatic answer has been established, to my knowledge". I've also pointed out that what is considered acceptable unarguably changes over time, with examples.  Please explain how this warrants "It is entirely unhelpful to tell people who are eager to know what to do and how to do it that it doesn't really matter ...". Have you access to (or do you consider yourself) an unassailable authority on the question here?

Comment: I taught to Oxbridge entrance exam level. Perhaps you should adopt a less arrogant and insolent approach and listen to this introduction to [Grammarphobia](http://www.grammarphobia.com/books-html/books_woe-html):  "Unlike, say, Latin, English is a living language— and, like all living things, it grows, it changes, it can be messy and confusing." And here is a recent warning that Grammarphobia is not Gospel:  "A: You’re right! Pat mistakenly pronounced the noun, a place for storing hay, as MOE, rather than MAU when she appeared on Talk of Iowa on July 8, 2015. Apologies are in order."

Comment: If you want a concensus, the 4 upvotes for Hot Licks' comment may be contrasted with the two downvotes for your answer. There is a lot of truth in what you say there, but English remains idiosyncratic, so arguing from the general to the specific is often unsound. 'The correct plural' will be determined on descriptive rather than prescriptive grounds. At the moment, as Hot Licks says, there is no consensus on OP's query.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I’ve never heard *computer *mouses* before; everyone I know always says *mice*.

Comment: @tchrist I wouldn't use 'mouses' myself, but what does that prove?

Comment: @tchrist It proves I know you. :)

Answer (score 3):

Often *coming out* is a verb form rather than a noun

> We bit the bullet and are *coming out* to our parents today!

No plural necessary.

Often it is an adjectival form

> We wanted a *coming out* party to share our happiness with the world.

No plural necessary.

Maybe when the gerund stands by itself, it should be considered an uncountable noun, like *beauty* or *freedom*

> After the Supreme Court decision, hundreds of couples celebrated their *coming out* in style.

Comment: That's it. So simple.  +1.

Comment: But what's being discussed is not one event involving multiple people, but multiple events over months or years.

Comment: @HotLicks There were a host of pundits at the debate. Their intelligence [not collective, each had some] was impressive. *Coming out* is rarely a discrete, definitive activity. It is more often a process that has numerous aspects and occasions. Like *truth-telling* or *honesty*.That's why I think uncountable is appropriate.

Comment: The answer is a way around the problem, not an answer to the question.

Comment: What "debate"?  The OP mentioned no debate.

Comment: @HotLicks It was meant to be an example of another uncountable noun (intelligence).

Comment: @JoostKiefte I think both common constructs, *comings-out* and *coming-outs* sound stilted and distract from the sense of the singular. I propose that the singular form be used, even in plural situations, as done with many other nouns for intangibles.

Comment: @bib Any stiltedness is in the eye of the beholder. Pity your eyesight is so bad.

Answer (score 0):

Hot Licks [already posted](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265513/plural-of-coming-out/266146#comment584019_265513) the answer as a comment, but comments can be expunged, so here it is as an answer:

> No idiomatic answer has been established You either wing it or tiptoe around it.

As RegDwigнt♦ posted in [yet a different comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265513/plural-of-coming-out/266146#comment587039_266146), there are many examples in English where the entire hyphenated phrase is treated as a single unit for pluralization:

> Yes, it's passers-by and not passer-bys. But it's also break-ups not breaks-up, blow-outs not blows-out, strike-outs not strikes-out, merry-go-rounds not merry-gos-round, etc. etc. (people in chat list dozens more). And yeah, coming-outs and not comings-out.

Google n-Grams shows that [*comings-out* has been in relatively widespread use for much longer than *coming-outs*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coming%20outs%2Ccomings%20out&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccoming%20outs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomings%20out%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccoming%20outs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomings%20out%3B%2Cc1):
[image]

Note that the graph shows a dramatic increase in the use of *coming-outs* in the last decade of data. If you click through to the results, you'll see that these are, indeed, true positives, where writers are using the phrase to refer to multiple instances of a closeted person revealing their secret (sexuality is the typical secret). Given that in much of the English-speaking world, gay people have had more coming(s)-out(s) recently, it's normal to see a spike in the usage of the phrase, but note that the overall distribution of the usage is almost evenly split between the two camps.

If there is a rule which determines where the pluralization is placed, it doesn't seem to be based on the "importance" of the component word, but rather on the component words' functions and whether or not the whole hyphenated phrase is taken as a single entity or not. I think there is more to this but haven't the time to look into it further.

TL,DR: Use *comings-out* if you want to be fussy. Use *coming-outs* if you want to be modern or if you feel strongly that the entire thing is one single unit word spelled with the hyphen letter.

Comment: *Passer-by* is different from *break-up*: the former is a noun with an attribute, which can and does function as a noun group directly. *Break-up* is from a verbal phrase, as in *to break up*. Hence the phrase is "quoted", as it were, when it is converted into a noun; and in this case quotation means that it cannot be changed internally after conversion. And it wouldn't make sense to do so, for *break* in *to break up* was never a noun before the conversion, and verbs don't get *-s* when they are pluralised.

Answer (score -3):

The correct plural is comings-out. Cf. passers-by, runners-up.

Grammarphobia.com gives the following rule:
“• If the word is split into parts, with or without hyphens, put the plural ending on the root or most important part:

*mothers*-in-law - *courts*-martial  - *ladies*-in-waiting  - *hangers*-on - *crêpes* suzette - *rear* admirals  - *men*-of-war - flag*ships* - tank *battalions* - *Johnnies*-come-lately (or alternatively Johnny-come-*latelies*)

“• Watch out for general when it’s part of a compound word. In a military title, general is usually the important part, so it gets the s. In a civilian title, general isn’t the root, so it doesn’t get the s:

Two attorneys general went dancing with two major generals. Those consuls general are retired brigadier generals.”

Comment: Where's your evidence this is correct?

Comment: '• If the word is split into parts, with or without hyphens, put the plural ending on the root or most important part'. As in _Johnny-come-latelies_? A serious flaw in this answer is that the quotation isn't attributed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth According to the Merriam-Webster online dictionary the plural can be either your version or Johnnies-come-lately. A serious flaw in your comment is that it's incomplete?

Comment: << The correct plural is comings-out. Cf. passers-by, runners-up.

Grammarphobia.com gives the following rule: “• If the word is split into parts, with or without hyphens, put the plural ending on the root or most important part >> is prescriptive. I gave a counterexample (two with _sending offs_, above) to show that it was over-prescriptive. I did not say you had to use 'Johnny-come-latelies' ...

Comment: (though [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Johnny-come-latelies%2CJohnnies-come-lately&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CJohnny%20-%20come%20-%20latelies%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CJohnnies%20-%20come%20-%20lately%3B%2Cc0) would seem to indicate clearly that this is the preferred version).